# how frequently iPad app (build using PhoneGap) can refresh itself?

Tags: ios

I have recently built an iPad app using PhoneGap. Currently it saves the last location I have visited and takes me there the next time I start the app (which is great and that's what I want!). Now my question is how frequently it will refresh itself when I start the app?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you allow backgrounding, applications don't refresh at all after the user hits the home button. Your application will remain exactly as it was when you last left it even if you wait a day or a week.